# Pressed (ripple) animation on button stops

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I have a drawer, and indside it a button, which among others closes drawer. When I press button, the pressed animation starts, when it's clicked the drawer closes, and then animation (pressed animation) stops, so when I open again drawer button is partly highlighted. How can make it to continue animation?

```
Drawer {
     id: drawer
     width: 0.66 * parent.width
     height: parent.height

     background: Rectangle {
         color: "#212121"
         anchors.fill: parent
      }

     ColumnLayout {
         Button {
             onClicked: {
                 drawer.close()
             }
             text: "<font color=\"#ffffff\">Lorem</font>"
             implicitHeight: 60
             implicitWidth: drawer.width
             flat: true
             Material.theme: Material.Dark
             Material.elevation: 0
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you list the exact steps you did to reproduce it? A GIF would be nice, too (you can use [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) for free if you're on Windows), or a screenshot.

Comment: I don't use AVD, because all x86 AVD devices can't run qml application, because there is opengl link problem. 
I actually solved the problem with the ripple animation by changing Button.qml (in qt folder installation). In the Ripple element I changed `control.Material.rippleColor` for `"transparent"`.

Comment: Can you answer the question and then accept it so we know it's solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved the problem with the ripple animation by changing Button.qml (in qt folder installation). In the Ripple element I changed `control.Material.rippleColor` for `"transparent"`.